# how to delete group instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, multiple-instances

When I am going to delete the group instance it always failed. The notification is that, but the problem is that I can not find the 'projects/windowtrafic/global/backendServices/backend' in google console.

The notification message:

*The instance_group_manager resource 'projects/windowtrafic/regions/asia-east1/instanceGroupManagers/instance-group-cchatty' is already being used by 'projects/windowtrafic/global/backendServices/backend'*

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the Load  Balancer that is using the groups instance.

Very important thing when you delete the LB don't forget to delete service backend, you can do that by checking the box during the LB deleting.

Answer (score -1):

If you ARE getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.delete) Could not check if 
the Managed Instance Group is Autoscaled.
 - Insufficient Permission
```

Check to make sure you are not attempting to delete the instance group from a VM instance that is a member of the instance group. The best approach is to use the Google Cloud Shell to delete the instance group. Your prompt will look similar to the following:

```
USER-NAME@PROJECT-NAME:~$ gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete [INSTANCE-GROUP-NAME] --zone [ZONE-NAME]
```

Alternatively, you can delete it delete the instance group from your [project console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceGroups/list?). From the Instance Group page, check the checkbox in front of the instance group name that you would like to delete, click on delete option on the top right menu.